# MYSQL query to sort GPS coordinates

Tags: mysql

I have a table with column 'gps' and it has comma separated latitude and longitude values.
(lat,lng)
If I want to sort the table by both latitude and longitude how can I do that?

UPDATE: I can sort by latitude

```
ORDER BY gps*1 asc/desc
```

but I want to sort by longitude as well

It would have been easy if I had two separate columns for latitude and longitude but I don't.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `substring_index` to locate `longitude` and `latitude`

EDIT:

```
select
SUBSTRING_INDEX(longitude_and_latitude, ',', 1) as longitude,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(longitude_and_latitude, ',', -1) as latitude
from MY_TABLE
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Use backticks around the field name.

Comment: such a rush with answering ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(gps, ',', 1)  AS longitude,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(gps, ',', -1) AS latitude
FROM   yourtable
ORDER  BY longitude,
          latitude
```

Comment: I don't know which answer should I accept... :) both are same